# beforeEach() function not running in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, automated-tests, protractor

I have written a spec file where its before function is not running at all.Following is the code I have written

```
var pageLoaded=false;

beforeEach(function(){

    if(!pageLoaded)
    {  
        browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
        browser.get('www.google.com',200000);

    }
});
```

The same SPEC file is working the other day and the code is not changed since then. Can anyone find any issue with this code?

Comment: What do you mean by before function is not running at all? Can you elaborate your problem? Where do you get errors or whats the behaviour of the application? Thanks

Comment: This looks OK to me, can you post the rest of the code please? Maybe we can see something in the rest of the code.

Comment: figured out the issue. I have added some code out of it block. removed the code and placed it in 'it' block and its working fine